# JQuery for scroll menu

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, scroll

I am trying to make a scroll bar ( just like the below example )
http://samples.infragistics.com/2010.3/WebFeatureBrowser/WebDataMenu/Scrolling/WebDataMenuScrolling.aspx

Its the 2nd example ( verticle one )

I was thinking of doing this in JQuery. Can anyone point me into the right direction on the steps i need to do to make this work? It should hide the down image as soon as it hits the last record too.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at existing jQuery plugins for [menus](http://plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins?type=44)

Either take one that works for you, or read the source / documentation / blogs and learn how to make one. You should

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins that fit the need. Google jquery content slider plugins

Also, you could look at the code for http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#tabs